# How can I improve my topology to prevent this feature when using subsurface modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

I'm trying to make this cylindrical object that is smooth and has sharp inner corners. The inner corners end up having a very strange effect on the outer smoothness of the object. I could make this effect by using a bool to remove cut out the inner corner after the subdivision, but it would be nice to just improve the topology. Any suggestions for how to model these inner corners so the curve continues nicely?

[image: Bad Topo]

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do it correctly with so few polygons

Comment: If I need to increase my number of polys that is fine. In general I haven't been able to find a simple way to avoid this problem. Ultimately I will be 3d printing this piece so the poly count isn't important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard corners on a round shape is always hard to achieve.
Firstly, you definitely shouldn't use mean crease to get that, it doesn't offer you enough control. It would be fine for quick preview modeling but not for precise retopology. Instead, you can use a Bevel modifier with a lower offset amount, two segments and 66° angle:

[image: bevel modifier]

Then, you could try doing this manual square bevel in your geometry:

[image: angle]

This isn't an ideal solution as it creates an n-gon with an irregularity. But it's definitely closer:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

You could begin with more vertices and try this type of topology:

[image]